# What does 'String count' mean in Dex file Android?

Tags: java, android, dex

From [adt-21-preview DOC](http://tools.android.com/download/adt-21-preview)

> Building
>
> There's a new flag to force "jumbo mode" for dex which allows a **larger number of strings** in the dex files; set dex.force.jumbo=true in project.properties

I red this [what-are-the-dex-method-and-string-limits-in-an-android-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634321/what-are-the-dex-method-and-string-limits-in-an-android-app)
 too, where `@SamWise` answers:

> With jumbo dex on, the string reference limit is somewhere between 110K and 120K.

**Question:**

What is *String* or *String reference* in Dex? Do they mean variable length? For example if I'll write:

```
private String foo = "fessy";
```

Doe it mean *string* is 3 or value length, in my case 5?

---

*Sub-question:*

I used following script [dex-method-counts](https://github.com/mihaip/dex-method-counts) to calculate method Count but I didn't find any reference to calculate *String* count.

Please help,

Answer (score 3):

All strings constants are stored in a dex file in a single sorted list. The strings are then referenced elsewhere in the dex file by index within that list.

These string indexes are generally an unsigned 32-bit integer. As far as the actual instructions go, there are 2 instructions that can reference a string: `const-string` and `const-string/jumbo`. The first takes a 16-bit string index, and the second takes a 32-bit string index.

So, the maximum number of strings is 2^32 = 4294967296

Comment: So in my case `private String foo = "fessy";` is String constant 1?

Comment: The string won't have an index until it's written to the dex file, and then it depends on where it fits with all the other strings in the dex file.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the OP's specific question:

```
private String foo = "fessy";
```

This would add **two new entries** to the string table, assuming no other class uses a variable called `foo`, and the string `"fessy"` does not appear anywhere else in your application.

If multiple independent classes use the same name for their variables/string literals, it only *adds a single entry* to the string table. This is one of the reasons to follow consistent naming conventions (ideally based on Android Framework code). Besides improving readability, it helps keeping the string count low.

You can easily **check the string count** by first extracting classes.dex from your apk file, and then dumping 4 bytes of the DEX header at offset 56 (see [Dalvik Executable format](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html)):

```
$ jar xvf app.apk classes.dex && hexdump -s 56 -n 4 -e '1/4 "%d\n"' classes.dex
```

The maximum number of strings for a (non-jumbo mode) dex file is 2^16 = 65,536.